# R Shiny Collapsible Boxes in sidebar panel / Sidebar panel with multiple collapsible boxes over full size

Tags: r, shiny, fluid-layout, shinybs

I want to create a `Shiny` app, which consists of different openable boxes on one side. In the boxes should then be buttons etc..

I have used the following solution so far:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyBS)

fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(# app title/description
    "ShinyApp"),
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1")),
    
    sidebarPanel(
      bsCollapsePanel(
        "Color Selection",
        actionButton("f1blue", "Blue"),
        actionButton("f1red", "Red"),
        actionButton("f2blue", "Blue"),
        actionButton("f2red", "Red"),
        style = "success"
      ),
      
     
    )
   
  )
)
```

Here is a visualization: I would like to avoid this "box within the box". This is what my current code generates:  [image]

And this is how it should look: Only collapsibles, no border and no margin through the sidebar panel:
[image]

Unfortunately this solution creates only a box in the sidebar panel. I would like to use collapsible boxes, which are as big as the sidebar panel or replace the panel with several boxes standing under each other. What should I do to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please be more precise on your desired output, so someone can help you.

Comment: Hi @YBS! Thank you for your comment. I have added an additional image to visualize how it should look. Thank You!